# Are DialogBox messages sent to a custom message loop?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application that currently has a message loop. If I were to create a modal dialog box with the `DialogBox` method would the current message loop receive messages from the dialog as well or would they be withheld by the runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DialogBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) creates its own message loop so your message loop will not run.  From the documentation:

> The function displays the dialog box (regardless of whether the
>   template specifies the WS_VISIBLE style), disables the owner window,
>   and starts its own message loop to retrieve and dispatch messages for
>   the dialog box.

Comment: I must have read right over that, now that I see it I feel kind of stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing message loop will not receive the messages for the dialog box. All messages for the dialog would be received by the *DLGPROC* method that you're passing as the last parameter to the *DialogBox* function.